# Ember-tools routes vs resources nested

Tags: ember.js, ember-tools

I just started with Ember, and after a couple tutorials am trying to build a larger app with ember tools. The generator let me build routes and templates in subdirectories by simply defining the path, but I can't get the resources to render the templates unless I pull them out of the subdirectory. There seems to be no problem with the templates being in folder. How do I define the resources in routes.js when they are in a subdirectory?

this doesn't work:

```
this.resource('schedule', function(){
    this.resource('daily');
});
```

but this does:

```
   this.resource('schedule', function(){
        this.route('daily');
    });
```

What's the difference to ember-tools? It worked with the ember starter kit to nest resources.

Comment: Could you provide more detail?

Comment: I got it, thank you. I had the child route named as a resource - but when I changed it to route, it worked. I'm not sure why, since when I was using the ember started kit, I could nest routes or resources, but with ember tools (and the subdirectory) only route worked.